# mail server for small MX domain & few email accounts

Tags: smtp, imap

Is there some free software mail server for Linux (at least IMAP + SMTP), offering also some web interface and good spam filtering, which is specialized for small MX (in the DNS) sense, and few email accounts. (e.g. less than 40 email accounts, and one or a few thousand emails per day, including spam). Actually I have two DNS domains on the same VPS (at OVH in France).

Ideally, I would like a single software package doing all that. (and of course, my goal is to avoid gmail).

<sup>(I don't mind some configuration work, and I am using Linux since 1994)</sup>

All the SMTP + IMAP servers I know (exim, postfix, sendmail, dovecot) are optimized for large traffic and many accounts; I would like something more integrated, but reliable. And SPAM filtering is done thru addons, all this being difficult to set up.

Some promising solution might be [IredMail](http://www.iredmail.org) (which does not work on Ubuntu 15.04)

PS my VPS is Ubuntu 15.04 (but I could change it to Debian 8 Jessie).

Comment: Software recommendation? I use `postfix`+`dovecot`+`spamassassin`+`clamav`+`mysql`+`postfixadmin` (if I remember well) for few accounts and few domains. I don't see any problem in this configuration, except the initial half-a-day of digging in configuration and making it working together.

Comment: Cumulated over several years, I spend more than a week configuring all these, and my VPS has still been blocked for spam...

Comment: But it is different case to make your mails go through. It requires to set up different tools (good test is for example http://www.mail-tester.com ). If you don't want to configure anything, there is Gmail. I don't think there is any application doing all of this. The protocols are old and rusty and people are usually happy that it "just works".

Comment: I do want to configure something, but I also want it to work reliably.

Comment: There is also Zimbra, but I have never heard about anyone who would be able to configure that (except our company instance). I configured `postfix` and friends on Debian based on this [czech article](http://blog.bcvsolutions.eu/mailserver-postfix-dovecot-a-mysql/) (probably not much helpful) and it seems still quite reliable after the years. I would rather focus on specific problems you have. Question how is asked will probably get closed as off-topic.